# Rails NoMethod Error when calling a dynamic attribute find

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am currently working on an app. In this app, I created a Person model and I was using rail's dynamic attribute find feature. In the Person model I have an attribute called uid, so I was calling Person.find_by_uid(some numerical value). This worked fine in my development mode and the app was totally functioning. However, once I deployed this app to heroku. The app failed and the log complains about NoMethodError (undefined method `find_by_uid' for #):

I have been looking all places, but still unable to track down the problem. I tried to define the method find_by_uid under the Person model, and still does not work.

I was wondering if anyone has had similar experience or knows how to solve this issue?

Thank you very much ahead of the time!

Comment: Have you run the migrations properly on Heroku? (`heroku rake db:migrate`)

Comment: heroku rake db:migrate followed by a heroku restart worked for me. I made the mistake of not running db:migrate first

Answer (score 3):

Did you try running the migrations in heroku (heroku rake db:migrate)? Most provably that attribute is not in the heroku data base so you don't have that dynamic method.

Comment: I ran "heroku restart" after the db:migrate and this worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. `heroku restart` has saved me.